# Split hateful people into groups that can exist in harmony (color a graph)

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math, directed-graphs

There are 51 people. Each person hates exactly 3 other people (who may or may not reciprocate). We need to split them into $n$ groups so that all groups exist in harmony.

> What is min $n$?

**Edit**
We need to find $n$ such that, *whatever* the graph, $n$ groups will be enough to accomplish our goal. I see it was not clear initially.

**Attempt**
Tried to prove $n=5$ by considering 1 parent and 3 children of a node. Hence 1(parent)+3(children)+1(self) = 5. But this solution fails to consider *other* parents

Comment: If there were 52 people, they could be split into 13 groups of 4 people each, all of whom hate one another.  Then we could divide them into 4 harmonious groups of 13 people, one from each group of 4.  With 51 people, this doesn't work of course, but 5 sounds like a good guess.

Comment: they do not necessarily hate one another. A may hate B, but B does not have to hate A in return

Comment: Yes, but I'm allowed to have them hate each other.

Comment: True. But it seems like it's not the worst case scenario. It seems to be 'worse' for $n$ when hatred is directed outside of the group is well.

Comment: Okay, I was considering a different (and easier) question.  I've deleted my answer.

Comment: edited the question to avoid confusion

Comment: At least $7$ groups are necessary. Suppose there seven people where, when arranged in a circle, each hates the people which are one, two and three spaces to their right. Then all $7$ of these people must be in separate groups.

Comment: I have rephrased the title to be more specific, but I do not insist on this particular phrasing, so feel free to change it to something else. (But "Enumerate nodes in a graph" is too vague and not even the thing we're doing here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phrase this as a coloring problem: we are trying to find a proper coloring of a graph whose vertices are the people, with an edge between two people whenever one of them hates the other.

This graph is $6$-degenerate: in any subgraph, there is a vertex of degree at most $6$. We can see this because the average degree in any subgraph is at most $6$ (if there are $n$ vertices in the subgraph, then there are at most $3n$ edges) and there must always be a vertex whose degree is at most the average degree.

A $k$-degenerate graph can be colored with $k+1$ colors, so this $6$-degenerate graph can be colored with $7$ colors: that is, we can separate the $51$ people into $7$ harmonious groups. We can do this recursively:

1. Pick some person involved in at most $6$ conflicts (that is, who is hated by at most $3$ people) and set them aside.
2. Partition the remaining $50$ people into $7$ harmonious groups using this same algorithm.
3. Put the person we set aside into a group that they have no conflicts with; this is possible because they have at most $6$ conflicts and we have $7$ groups.

This is best possible, since (as pointed out in the comments) the graph could contain a $K_7$: if among the first $7$ people numbered $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$, person $i$ hates $\{i+1,i+2,i+3\} \bmod 7$, then no two of these can be in the same group together. So we can't do better than $7$ groups.

A more general result can be found in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581217/bounds-on-the-chromatic-number-of-a-directed-graph-given-bounds-on-out-degree).

Comment: Can you please explain why the average degree in any subgraph is at most 6? The inference should be smarter than just $3n/n$, and I do not get it yet

Comment: It is not any smarter than that. Out of every vertex we have at most $3$ edges going out, for a total of $3n$, and therefore the average number of edges going into a vertex is at most $\frac{3n}{n} =3$, for a total of $3+3=6$.