Smallest number of groups
Eighty-four developers sign up to contribute to a public open-source project. You need to divide the developers into $n$ subteams such that each contributor is on exactly one team. Their personalities are such that for each developer $d$ there are exactly three others with whom $d$ refuses to  work. (These refusals aren’t necessarily symmetric: that developer $b$ is one of the people developer $a$ refuses to work with does not imply that $b$ also refuses to work with $a$.) Find the smallest $n$ such that it is always possible to arrange the teams so that no contributor hates another contributor on their team.
Here's what I've done:
I tried modelling this as a graph problem, where each person is a vertex and there is an edge $ij$ if and only if $i$ hates $j$ or vice versa. and the question reduces to finding chromatic number of such graph, it is easy to see that there is some configuration under which chromatic number is at least 7 (you can create the following construction : arrange 7 nodes and go around in a circle say clockwise and create edge between node $i$ and $i+1$, $i+2$, $i+3$ (mod 7)).
My guess is 7 teams would be enough in any case, but I cannot prove it, any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Your idea works right? The chromatic number is $\leq$ max degree + 1, using a similar argument to what you outlined. $\quad$ You then need to provide a configuration where 6 doesn't work, in order to show that 7 is the smallest.

but 7 is just a lower-bound, chromatic number of more than 7 is not ruled out. 6 of course doesn't work because I've shown I definitely need atleast 7 colors in some configuration. also max_degree could be 83 (in case of one particular person is hated by every one else) so that upper bound doesn't help too much

See this question and answers provided there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581217/bounds-on-the-chromatic-number-of-a-directed-graph-given-bounds-on-out-degree

@dbal thanks a lot, that helps
